# Nodes Express App.Route Path Confuse the Other folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am use Nodes.js Express to do my route.

For the normal one... localhost:8080/Order its go work wells. But i am try to use use get method with the ID method localhost:8080/Order/ID-12345 and continue to ViewOrder.html to perform the function. But its shown out some error.

Error
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
localhost:1337/**Orders**/img/p7.jpg

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
localhost:1337/**Orders**/css/bootstrap.min.css

and etc..

Instead of 
localhost:1337/css/bootstrap.min.css

```
// Index Page 

app.get('/Order', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/Orders/:item', function (req, res) {

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/ViewOrder.html');

});
```

**Order** and **Orders** is not a directory. I used part of the route
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpPi9.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph2JL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep! You need to specify your static folders in order serve static files.
So in your case i would do this to your server.js ;)

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
http = require('http').Server(app);

const ipaddress = "127.0.0.1";
const port = 1337;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/Order'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/Orders'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
 res.sendFile('index.html', {"root": __dirname});
});

app.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
 var param=req.params.id;/// hu! gotcha little param
 res.sendFile('Orders/index.html', {"root": __dirname});
});

http.listen(port, ipaddress, function () {
 console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port' + port);
});
```

---

UPDATE - according to comment (*Actually Order is not a directory, I use Order as route to linked to directory – Brian*)

Pretend a public folder would be your root/static this would be my second attempt

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/Order', function (req, res) {
 res.sendFile('public/index.html', {"root": __dirname});
});

app.get('/Orders/:item', function (req, res) {
 res.sendFile('public/ViewOrder.html', {"root": __dirname});
});
```

**attention**
i had to modify static requests

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

               - TO - 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
```

Comment: Actually Order is not a directory, I use Order as route to linked to directory

Comment: Ahh i see! ok! Pretend a public folder would be root/static this would be my second attempt (see above!)

Comment: I am try the method, its load successfully the css. but its help me load the the files several times. https://ufile.io/mpu75 if i run it seperately without the :item its able to run it

Answer (score 1):

In your file server.js (the file that start your application) have you set the static dirname?

For me this resolve your problem:

```
var app = express();
app.use('/Orders', express.static(__dirname));
```

This setting set up the statics file for your project.

For more information this is helpfull [express static resources](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your html pages to load css/js assets your need to serve them as static file ( documentation : http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html )

Answer (score 0):

The image and bootstrap file can't be loaded because you haven't specified a static folder.

`app.use('/media', express.static(__dirname + '/media'));`

Using this, all files in the media folder can be requested by refering to them with `/media/img/p7.jpg`.

You may as well change the request path:

`app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/your/real/path'));`

Thus you can refer to them like `/static/img/p7.jpg`.